# Convex Function identity if lambda > 1

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is convex on $I$ and $a<b<c \in I \implies  f(x)\geq \frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b) + \frac{b-x}{b-a}f(a)$ for $b<x<c\\$
I already know that we have $f(x)\leq \frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b) + \frac{b-x}{b-a}$ for $a<x<b$. Using this it is clear that $\frac{x-a}{b-a}>1$ and $\frac{b-x}{b-a}<0$. I can work it out with simple examples and see that it is clearly true but can't get any steam to begin with. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the above inequality is equivalent to

$$f(b)\leq \frac{x-b}{x-a} f(a) + \frac{b-a}{x-a} f(x)$$ for $b<x<c.$